# PHP: measure TTFB (Time To First Byte)

Tags: php, performance, measurement

Since the TTFB can vary by every request, I want to make a statistic and get an average value for it. Does anyone know how I can measure this via PHP?
The website bytecheck.com is able to analyze these data:
Here is an example with example.com: http://www.bytecheck.com/results?resource=example.com

Does anyone a suggestions how I could achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this with curl:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "TTFB of ".$url." is: ".$info['starttransfer_time'];
```

Result

```
TTFB of https://www.example.com/ is: 0.67417
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for this, but none of my Google queries led me to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good Curl wrapper here: 
https://packagist.org/packages/curl/curl

If you already have installed Composer, just do 'composer require curl/curl' and use it.

Regards.